# how to Find unique values in a column?Attribute Error: "DataFrame" object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy, unique

I am making a generic tool which can take up any csv file.I have a csv file which looks something like this. The first row is the column name and the second row is the type of variable.

```
Time,M1,M2,M3,CityName
temp,num,num,num,city
20-May-13,19,20,0,aligarh
20-May-13,25,42,7,agra
20-May-13,23,35,4,aligarh
20-May-13,21,32,3,allahabad
20-May-13,17,27,1,aligarh
20-May-13,16,40,5,aligarh
```

I want to find unique values in the column where the type of the variable is "city",i.e, the second row. I have been able to search the column name where the type is "city" and try to find the unique values but could not succeed further as it gives error.

```
filename = 'sam.csv'
data_date = pd.read_csv(filename)
column_name = data_date.ix[:, data_date.loc[0] == "city"]
column_work = column_name.iloc[1:]
name = column_work.dtypes.index
column_unique = data_date.column_work.unique()
print(column_unique)
```

I want the unique values in a list, such as,

```
[aligarh,agra,allahabad]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unique`+`tolist`

```
column_work.CityName.unique().tolist()
Out[87]: ['aligarh', 'agra', 'allahabad']
```

Comment: I cannot use the column name  as "CityName" as it is a generic application and can take any csv file. The column name could be different.

Comment: @KuhuGupta than change to column_work.iloc[:,0].unique().tolist()

Comment: I tried using the caluclated "name" variable in place of "CityName" but it gives me an error.